# Declarative Auth blocking instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, instance-variables, declarative-authorization

I'm using declarative authorization in my rails app, and I have the following controller:

```
class OrganizationsController < ApplicationController
  filter_resource_access attribute_check: true

  def index
    @organizations = Organization.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @organizations }
    end
  end
end
```

However when I try to access the view for that action, I get the error
`undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` on the line where I try to access the `@organizations` instance variable. It works when I comment out the `filter_resource_access` line.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

the error is because your instance variable is Nil, is why it says undefined method each for nil:NilClass. filter is a method that runs either before or after the controller, in this case i'm not exactly sure what that method means but its not letting you access the data until after the controller is my guess.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I forgot to include the declarative_authorization gem in my Gemfile.  :shame:

All is working now.